# Google Cloud CDN won't cache https pages because they have Vary header x-forwarded-proto

Tags: caching, google-cloud-cdn

It seems I can't use Google Cloud CDN with GKE Ingress in https requests, because the Ingress controller adds a Vary http header: x-forwarded-proto, which CDN won't cache (see https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#non-cacheable_content). I think it's correct that the header is added, because it tells the application serving the content that it's being requested as https. But I'm not sure why CDN won't cache pages with this header.

Am I missing something or is there a workaround?

Example of header when page is requested as http and *is* cached:

```
 Age: 1713
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2000
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 8503
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 20:56:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 google
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.9
```

Example of header when page is requested as http and *isn't* cached:

```
    alt-svc: clear
cache-control: public, max-age=2000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 8499
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 21:25:37 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
status: 200
vary: X-Forwarded-Proto,Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 google
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.9
```

Many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

As you already confirmed the Cloud CDN won't cache it due to this header. This would be expected.

Regarding that header which is added, you will need to review why it's added and find a way to remove it if you want to cache this content with Cloud CDN. I found a few article that you can review:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/51
- https://serverfault.com/questions/912168/how-to-make-google-cloud-load-balancer-respect-the-received-x-forwarded-proto
- https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1181

You would have to find a solution to remove this header based on your deployment.